# MEAN stack app robots.txt not performing as expected

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt

I am trying to use robots.txt to allow crawling public links on my SPA,  but to disallow other links to the site. When I use the robots.txt tester by Google, it does not differentiate between the two kinds of links and either allows both of them, or none of them.

Typical links are:

1. to be disallowed: https://www.example.org/index.html#!/user/lessons/53f9b74f264b02126b0300f2/intro
2. to be allowed: 
   https://www.example.org/index.html#!/public/lessons/53f9b74f264b02126b0300f2/intro

I have tried :

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /public/
Disallow: /
```

and this:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /public/
Disallow: /user/
```

but either both were blocked or neither were blocked. 
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: It may be that anything from #! will be ignored.

Comment: I agree that that this makes it more complex to deal with, but google does crawl the site and finds thousands of links, so I would expect them to have a solution to blocking them as well.

Comment: Except that robots.txt is not designed to be that grandular. It may be that you will need to use noindex or nofollow.

Comment: I do have a noindex directive on the site, but I don't see how it can be used for this situation. The public links have the same html file as the non public(user) only the path is different. Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like whatever you do will have to be done in your CMS or code. I assume you have a login for private users. If that is the case, are you requiring a login for /user? If a login is required, then your work should be done assuming you have set this up correctly. Google will try and follow any link it finds. For users who are not logged on, they should not see private links. This includes Google unless you want these pages indexed also. I do not recommend indexing pages that ordinary search users cannot see. That is bad UX (user experience) in my book. Cheers!

Comment: You are correct in your assumptions. If Google follows a /user link, it will show the login page. If I understand you correctly, Google will then learn which links are 'active' and which are not, and so eventually only the good links will be scraped. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sort of. Any request for a private page for anyone who is not logged on should be 301 redirected to the login page which should have a noindex. This is common but not always the case. If not the case, I am not sure what Google does in these cases, however, these pages should all but be excluded as duplicate anyway. I haven't had a site with a login for quite a long time. It is likely one of our experts can help you with the details. We tend to be slow on the weekends, after all we are professionals and go home for the weekends, there are still enough around that someone should come by soon.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the comments from closetnoc and my understanding:

robots.txt does not work for sites using `#!` to either allow or disallow folders in the 'fragment' ie, after the `#!`.

It can be used to change access to folders or files not preceded by #!. For example: `Disallow: /backend/crawler`

If you do not want links to be crawled, then the endpoint of the link should be `noindex`file, such as after a redirect to a login page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: */user/*
```

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem.